# Create a nice counter circle in HTML/CSS Jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css, animation, geometry

I would like to display my data nicely on my website.

I love this [counter circle](https://avada.theme-fusion.com/counter-circles/)

I made some research, but nothing is as beautiful and as practical as the one I mentioned above...

The best I found is this one [codepen](http://codepen.io/rendro/pen/vrezp)

```
@import "compass/css3";

body {
  font: 12px/1.4 'Helvetica','Arial', sans-serif;
  color: #a1a7a6;
  background: #e0e3db;
}
.panel{
  position: relative;
  background: #fff;
  width: 300px;
  margin: 40px auto;
  text-align: center;
  @include border-radius(4px);
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.15);
}
.chart{
  display: inline-block;
  width: 110px;
  margin: 40px auto 20px;
  padding: 0 10px;
}
.easyPieChart {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  canvas {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
  }
}
.percentage,
.label {
    margin-bottom: 0.5em;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: 100;
}
.percentage{
  font-size: 17px;
}
sup{
  top: -0.2em;
  margin-left: 1px;
}
.ctrl{
  position: absolute;
  right: 10px;
  top: 5px;
  color: #c4cdcc;
  word-spacing: 5px;
  span{   
    cursor: pointer;
    @include transition(color .5s ease-in-out);
    &:hover{
      color: #000;
    }
  }
}

.meta{
  margin: auto;
  max-width: 280px;
  border-top: 1px solid rgba(155,155,155,0.2);
  text-align: center;
}

p{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 20px;
  color: lighten(#a1a7a6, 15%);
  a{
    color: inherit;
    text-decoration: none;
    border-bottom: 1px solid currentColor;
  }
  +p{
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
  }
}
```

However, I can't remove the small bars around the circle, I can't display a float number, I can't change the color and the size easily etc...

Does anyone knows a good plugin that is able to do this?
Or can you explain how to remove the bars around the circle and display a float inside? (For example 4,634).

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I couldn't remove the dashes, so I started looking for something else. Here is what I found, it looks good in my opinion: https://codepen.io/DeptofJeffAyer/pen/ogPbPG

Comment: Well, to display floats just remove the `Math.round`, or modify it, so it gives you a set number of positions after decimal point.  If you want to remove the lines, well you will have to dig into the code behind the plugin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove the scale lines with :

```
scaleColor: false
```

To display floats without modifying the plugin, you must store the initial values :

```
var v0 = $('.chart span:eq(0)');
var v1 = $('.chart span:eq(1)');

var values = [v0.text(), v1.text()];

$('.percentage').easyPieChart({
  scaleColor: false,
  animate: 1000,
  lineWidth: 4,    
  onStep: function(value) {
    this.$el.find('span').text(Math.round(value));
  },
  onStop: function(value, to) {    
     v0.text(values[0]);
     v1.text(values[1]);
  }
});
```